# Port forwarding (through 2 routers) to raspberry pi tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, raspberry-pi, router, portforwarding

I have a raspberry pi, and I set up apache and tomcat and ssh.
I can connect to all of them with the local IP address:
192.168.1.121:80, 192.168.1.121:8080, 192.168.1.121:22 with no problem.

I set static ip to the pi and to the second router too. I set port forwarding on the second router for 80, 8080 and 22 ports to the pi, and on the first router to the second router (same ports).

I use the noip client to refresh the dynamic dns service. **I can reach the ssh and the apache, but I can't the tomcat.** So I can connect to the mydomain.no-ip.info and the mydomain.no-ip.info:22 but I can't to the mydomain.no-ip.info:8080.

I think it's strange, because **all of them should work or none of them**... What can be the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I found in the /etc/tomcat7/server.xml file two possible wrong settings:

```
...
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

...

    <Host name ="localhost" ... >
```

Should I change one of (or both of) the localhost to mydomain.no-ip.info?

**UPDATE2:**
If I change the Host to mydomain.no-ip.info I get an empty page for 192.168.1.121:8080, and error for mydomain.no-ip.info:8080. If I change both the 192.168.1.121:8080 is working, but the domain:8080 **still not**.

**UPDATE3:**
I scanned the 8080 port with this tool: http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/ and it says it's open. So I think my ISP is not blocking the 8080 port (ok, if 80 is not blocked, the 8080 has a little chance to be blocked)

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -plantu | grep -E -- '8080|22|:80 ` on the server? Are you able to reach `8080` from within your local network? And are you able to reach your server's other ports from either router, for example if the things are setup like 'ISP' `<->` 'RouterA` `<->` `RouterB`, are you able to connect to the server regardless of which router you are connected to?

Answer (score 0):

no-ip.info probably blocks port 8080.
Try connecting with your external ip directly.

Comment: Good idea. I tried with the external ip directly, but can't connect to 8080. The 80 and 22 ports are ok.
In this doc from noip they say you can use 8080 for a webcam for example: http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/port-forwarding-a-vigor2110-v3-3-6-router/

Answer (score 0):

With nmap I did some port scan, and I see that the 192.168.0.1 (first router) 8080 port is closed. It's strange, because the external ip's 8080 port is open (see update3).

I changed the tomcat port to 8181, set the forwarding on both routers, and it's working with mydomain.no-ip.info:8181

It's working now, but an explanation is welcomed.